# Android: how to create post xml-rpc request with custom http header & content type

Tags: java, android, xml-rpc

I want to creat xml-rpc POST request, and pass 2 parameters "application_name" & "key", and change content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" like my code below.

```
try {
        XMLRPCClient oneTimeKeyClient = new XMLRPCClient(new URL(URL_REQUEST_SAMPLE), XMLRPCClient.FLAGS_DEFAULT_TYPE_STRING);
        oneTimeKeyClient.setCustomHttpHeader("X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE", "POST");
```

//            oneTimeKeyClient.setCustomHttpHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

```
        HashMap<String, String> oneTimeKeyParam = new HashMap<>();
        oneTimeKeyParam.put("application_name", "hello_app");
        oneTimeKeyParam.put("key", "bb5eb953d3b41dcf59f4669d98f8e14782ed83133be772956b");
        Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();
        params.add(oneTimeKeyParam);

        oneTimeKeyClient.callAsync(new XMLRPCCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(long id, Object response) {
                try {
                    result = ((Map) response).get(NAME_ONE_TIME_KEY).toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Timber.e("onParseError %s", e.getMessage());
                    DialogUtil.showLoginErrorDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(long id, XMLRPCException error) {
                Timber.e("onError %s", error.getMessage());
                DialogUtil.showLoginErrorDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());
            }

            @Override
            public void onServerError(long id, XMLRPCServerException error) {
                Timber.e("onServerError %s", error.getMessage());
                DialogUtil.showLoginErrorDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());
            }
        }, "", params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e("onError %s", e.getMessage());
        DialogUtil.showLoginErrorDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
```

I got error " onServerError APPLICATION_NAME must record not exists."
I using aXMLRPC library https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC .
Which library do you recommend ? 
Can I use Retrofit to make xml-rpc request ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use retrofit like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("onetime_key")
Observable<OneTimeKeyRes> requestOneTimeKey(@Field("application_name") String applicationName, @Field("key") String key);
```

You must add SimpleXmlConverter:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(builder.build())
            .baseUrl(YOUR_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```